# SQL Server 2005 proper index to filter 30,000,000 registers

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, indexing, large-data-volumes

I have a problem with a stored procedure of a transactional table, the user have a web form to find transactions by several values.

The process is taking too long and I don't know how to set proper index.

here is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.cg_searchTransactions
(
    @id_Ent tinyint,
    @transactionTypeID int = NULL,
    @transactionID numeric(18,0) = NULL,
    @channelID int = NULL,
    @transactionDateFrom datetime = NULL,
    @transactionDateTo datetime = NULL,
    @transactionStatusID INT = NULL,
    @documentType INT = NULL,
    @documentNumber varchar(50) = NULL,
    @userName varchar(50) = NULL,
    @accountFromNumber varchar(20) = NULL,
    @accountToNumber varchar(20) = NULL,
    @amountFrom money = NULL,
    @amountTo money = NULL,
    @correlationID varchar(30) = NULL,
    @externalReference varchar(20) = NULL,
    @externalReference2 varchar(20) = NULL,
    @PageIndex INT = 1, 
    @PageSize INT = 20
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON


        DECLARE @QUERY VARCHAR(MAX)
        SET @QUERY = '
            WITH Trans AS (
            SELECT
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY transactionID DESC) AS Row,
                T.id_Ent,
                T.transactionID,
                T.trnTypeCurrencyID,
                T.transactionDate,
                T.transactionStatusID,
                T.documentType,
                T.documentNumber,
                T.childDocumentType,
                T.childDocumentNumber,
                T.userName,
                T.accountFromNumber,
                T.accountFromType,
                T.accountFromCurrency,
                T.accountDescriptionFrom,
                T.costCenterFrom,
                T.subtotalFrom,
                T.taxamountFrom,
                T.taxamountFrom2,
                T.amountFrom,
                T.accountToNumber,
                T.accountToType,
                T.accountToCurrency,
                T.accountDescriptionTo,
                T.costCenterTo,
                T.subtotalTo,
                T.taxamountTo,
                T.taxamountTo2,
                T.amountTo,
                T.exchangeCurrency,
                T.traderAuthNumber,
                T.benefContractNumber,
                T.contractNumber,
                T.merchantID,
                T.creditCardAuthorizationNumber,
                T.comment,
                T.companyServiceCommision,
                T.usercommission,
                T.companyServiceAuthorizationNumber,
                T.customerBranchId,
                T.correlationID,
                T.transactionStartTime,
                T.transactionEndTime,
                T.enlapsedTime,
                T.serverName,
                T.externalReference,
                T.externalReference2,
                T.externalTrxType,
                T.beneficiaryName,

                C.shortName AS ChannelsShortName,
                TT.shortName AS TransactionTypesShortName,
                TS.shortName AS TransactionStatusDefShortName,
                DT.shortName AS DocumentTypesShortName,
                CDT.shortName AS ChildDocumentTypesShortName,
                AFT.shortName AS AccountTypesShortNameFrom,
                ATT.shortName AS AccountTypesShortNameTo,
                CURF.shortName AS CurrenciesShortNameFrom,
                CURT.shortName AS CurrenciesShortNameTo
            FROM
                Transactions T (NOLOCK) 

                    INNER JOIN TransactionTypesCurrencies TTC
                        ON  T.id_Ent = TTC.id_Ent
                            AND T.trnTypeCurrencyID = TTC.trnTypeCurrencyID

                        INNER JOIN Channels C
                            ON  TTC.id_Ent = C.id_Ent
                                AND TTC.channelID = C.ID

                        INNER JOIN TransactionTypes TT
                            ON  TTC.id_Ent = TT.id_Ent
                                AND TTC.transactionTypeID = TT.transactionTypeID

                    INNER JOIN TransactionStatusDef TS
                        ON  T.id_Ent = TS.ent_Ent
                            AND T.transactionStatusID = TS.ID

                    INNER JOIN DocumentTypes DT
                        ON  T.id_Ent = DT.id_Ent
                            AND T.documentType = DT.ID

                    INNER JOIN DocumentTypes CDT
                        ON  T.id_Ent = CDT.id_Ent
                            AND T.childDocumentType = CDT.ID

                    INNER JOIN AccountTypes AFT
                        ON  T.id_Ent = AFT.id_Ent
                            AND T.accountFromType = AFT.ID

                    INNER JOIN AccountTypes ATT
                        ON  T.id_Ent = ATT.id_Ent
                            AND T.accountToType = ATT.ID

                    INNER JOIN Currencies CURF
                        ON  T.id_Ent = CURF.id_Ent
                            AND T.accountFromCurrency = CURF.ID

                    INNER JOIN Currencies CURT
                        ON  T.id_Ent = CURT.id_Ent
                            AND T.accountToCurrency = CURT.ID
            WHERE 
                T.id_Ent = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@id_Ent)
                IF NOT @transactionDateFrom IS NULL
                    SET @QUERY = @QUERY + ' AND T.transactionDate >= ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@transactionDateFrom,121) + ''''

                IF NOT @transactionDateTo IS NULL
                    SET @QUERY = @QUERY + ' AND T.transactionDate <= ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@transactionDateTo,121) + ''''

                IF NOT @transactionStatusID IS NULL
                    SET @QUERY = @QUERY + ' AND T.transactionStatusID = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@transactionStatusID)

                IF NOT @documentType IS NULL
                    SET @QUERY = @QUERY + ' AND T.documentType = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@documentType)

                IF NOT @userName IS NULL
                    SET @QUERY = @QUERY + ' AND T.userName = ''' + @userName + ''''

                IF NOT @documentNumber IS NULL
                    SET @QUERY = @QUERY + ' AND T.documentNumber = ''' + @documentNumber + ''''

                IF NOT @accountFromNumber IS NULL
                    SET @QUERY = @QUERY + ' AND T.accountFromNumber = ''' + @accountFromNumber + ''''

                IF NOT @accountToNumber IS NULL
                    SET @QUERY = @QUERY + ' AND T.accountToNumber = ''' + @accountToNumber + ''''

                IF NOT @amountFrom IS NULL
                    SET @QUERY = @QUERY + ' AND T.amountTo >= ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@amountFrom)

                IF NOT @amountTo IS NULL
                    SET @QUERY = @QUERY + ' AND T.amountTo <= ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@amountTo)

                IF NOT @correlationID IS NULL
                    SET @QUERY = @QUERY + ' AND T.correlationID = ''' + @correlationID + ''''

                IF NOT @externalReference IS NULL
                    SET @QUERY = @QUERY + ' AND T.externalReference = ''' + @externalReference + ''''

                IF NOT @externalReference2 IS NULL
                    SET @QUERY = @QUERY + ' AND T.externalReference2 = ''' + @externalReference2 + ''''

                IF NOT @channelID IS NULL
                    SET @QUERY = @QUERY + ' AND C.ID = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@channelID)

                IF NOT @transactionTypeID IS NULL
                    SET @QUERY = @QUERY + ' AND TT.transactionTypeID = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@transactionTypeID)

            SET @QUERY = @QUERY + ')'
            SET @QUERY = @QUERY + 'SELECT * FROM Trans WHERE Row BETWEEN (' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@PageIndex) + ' - 1) * ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@PageSize) + ' + 1 AND ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@PageIndex) + '*' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@PageSize)

            SET @QUERY = @QUERY + 'OPTION (FAST 1)'

            EXEC(@QUERY)

END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to create the separate indexes on all fields used in the `WHERE` clause, that is `transactionDate`, `transactionStatusID` etc. If you have a `id_ent` as an additional filter, include it as a leading column:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_transaction_transactionDate ON transaction (id_ent, transactionDate)
CREATE INDEX ix_transaction_transactionStatusID ON transaction (id_ent, transactionStatusID)
-- etc.
```

Note that for each query only one index will be used, and `SQL Server` will try to select the most appropriate one (the most selective one).

Also note that placing a `NOLOCK` hint on a production table is a very bad idea. You can have dirty reads *within a single query*.

If the `id_ent` is a part of a `PRIMARY KEY` in all of your tables, you better replace it with the constant. This query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Transactions t
JOIN    TransactionTypesCurrencies ttc
ON      ttc.trnTypeCurrencyID = t.trnTypeCurrencyID 
WHERE   t.id_ent = @id_ent
        AND ttc.id_ent = @id_ent
```

is generally better than this one:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Transactions t
JOIN    TransactionTypesCurrencies ttc
ON      ttc.id_ent = t.id_ent
        AND ttc.trnTypeCurrencyID = t.trnTypeCurrencyID 
WHERE   t.id_ent = @id_ent
```

, since the early filtering can be done.

This makes no difference if you have only a single value of `id_ent`, but will pay for itself if you will ever add another one.

**Update:**

If you have the recurring queries that filter on more than one conditions and are slow, you can consider creating additional composite indexes on several conditions.

See this article in my blog for some suggestions on how to do this:

- [**Creating indexes**](http://explainextended.com/2009/05/09/creating-indexes/)

Comment: thanks in advance. the problem is that i can search for any combination of fields, can be Date and Transaction Type or Transaction Type and User ID, etc etc etc... and other thing is that the guy that create this table makes the field Id_Ent as part of the primary key (id_ent + transactionID) but id_ent is the same value in the entire table, i  ask him to change that because it can affect my index, isnt it?

Comment: It's OK to have a composite PK as long as you always filter on the first portion of the PK (which I see you do).

Comment: yeah id_Ent is on all of the tables, im actually doing the JOINS as you say "ttc.id_ent = t.id_ent", also in creating all the index to test your suggestion i let you know this way... thanks

Comment: `@jmpena`: Great. Just get rid of that `NOLOCK`, ok? :)

Comment: ok i will (im reading something about it to understand  when or why use that) the main problem on my case is that im a software programer not a DBA but in this part of the project i dont think the company will contract one.

Comment: `NOLOCK` means allowing dirty reads (the data which are changed but not yet commited). Usually this clause is misused for "fighting deadlocks". It does not fight deadlocks but it does get prevent some lock contentions: the queries which would normally block just return incorrect results.

Answer (score 0):

You can get some empirical information by using the profiler to record a workload and then use the index tuning wizard with that workload to determine the indexes best able to handle the workload.

The more indexes you create, the more work that inserts will have to do, so creating indexes on everything being searched on might not be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I found that in this scenario it can be quicker to create a temp table rather than a common table expression.  This also allows you to return the total number for paging.

Comment: a tmp table for more than 30,000,000 i think it will hurts, by the way i use a similar query with count(*) for the record count but in this case i dont need it, the user will pagind until he get a "No records found on this page" message.

Comment: You would still build the where clause like you have, but that would be used to populate the temp table, which could then give the total number of items within that filter and return any page requested.

Answer (score 0):

Questions which I ask myself before I create an index:

1. Is this table(or tables) going to be read only or read write ?

ReadWrite - everytime there is an update/delete to the table, the index would be updated.it might be fast for "select" but slow for insert,update and delete. [To quote MS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998577.aspx#scalenetchapt14%20_topic8) "If you have a large number of indexes on a table, you increase the chance that the optimizer will choose a suboptimal index for a query plan."

2. You are creating queries on the fly.What I would do is try to run trace on QA (or production DB for a specific time) and see what the users are trying to run. You can get a dump of the DB from production to your sandbox/ try tools like index tuning wizard (which can tell you what indexes are needed) , [SQL DMVs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966540.aspx) etc to find where the bottleneck is.  The problem need not be only with this SP, but there might be deadlocks, improper use of temp tables/ temp DB etc.
3. If you are reasonably confident that this table is the culprit, you should also try partitioning the table horizontally
4. When you execute any query, look at the execution plan and look for table scans- which usually means that some index is missing
5. [Read](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735621969), [Read](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=3&ved=0CA0QFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fkrishnan.co.in%2Fblog%2Fpost%2F9-Free-eBooks-on-SQL-Server-and-performance.aspx&rct=j&q=SQL+Server+eBook+Selection&ei=IGkiS7jKCM-rlAeUnamJCg&usg=AFQjCNG-8bPuURjqBIgleYEyduBs7TpMxw&sig2=dH_IZItl5hYJM27jlybqCg) and [Read](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/sqldodont.aspx).

Comment: thanks for the information, this is a transactional table, only for inserts and selects (not update or deletes).

i want to use a mirror table so if the user want real time reports can use that table indexed and leave the transactional table operable, i think is a better idea.